# Detect rails server shutdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shutdown, server

How to detect any Rails server shutdown **from within Rails application**? I am looking for a solution which may work with WEBrick, Puma, Unicorn, Passenger.

What I want to do on server shutdown is to send message through WebSockets and set terminate flag to Web Sockets server to make it shut down properly.

Answer (score -2):

You should run secondary rails app on another server sharing same database.
And you need to send ajax request regularly to the main app to check termination, 
and you can send ajax request to secondary app when main app is terminated and send email or whatever.

Comment: How will you guarantee that the copy of application answering is the copy that does not want to unload and not the newly started? How can you guarantee that web app will not manage to stop and start again between your AJAX requests before you even detect the shutdown? Why AJAX (do you plan to do a watchdog with JavaScript?)? And so on and so forth. Completely incompetent answer.